# Eclipse plug-in for python remote development

Tags: python, eclipse-plugin, amazon-ec2, pydev, remote-desktop

I'm a data-scientist looking to upgrade my analysis workflow.

I'm considering moving from my office workstation to EC2 in AWS (as the DB I'm fetching data from is there, and downloading large chunks is slow).

I'm working with Eclipse PyDev to run/debug my scripts (which are based mostly on NumPy/SciPy).

Remote desktop is pretty slow with my current web connection.

my question:
Is there some eclipse plug-in that will allow me to code locally, and have the script run/debug on a CE2 instance that I will setup?

Comment: PyCharm from JetBrains does this seamlessly.  Makes local development/remote deployment a pleasure.  Best IDEs on the market.

Comment: Did you read about [PyDev's remote debugging functionality](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html)? I haven't used Eclipse in ages, and even back then never used the remoted debugger, but sounds like it should be doable (unless there's EC2 specifics that complicate it).

Comment: Also: There's many different ways to accomplish this. Two others that come to mind are [version control and automated deployment](http://danbarber.me/using-git-for-deployment/) or a [network file system](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System).